# Создать торрет файл через golang

Tags: golang, torrent

Есть ли примеры golang кода создания торрент файла?
Код не должен использовать под капотом никаких внешних утилит

Comment: https://github.com/polvi/mktorrent/blob/master/mktorrent.go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проект rain https://github.com/cenkalti/rain

Создание торрента
https://github.com/cenkalti/rain/blob/master/main.go#L929

Comment: А можете в ответе показать пример использования?

Comment: К сожалению нет, я использовал данную библиотеку, чтоб понять как написть  свою реализацию функции создания торрент файла